# How to look up for exact same objects with .contains() method in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

The idea is simple I don't need to add objects that are already on the list. I guess the problem is that it creates a completely new object and it doesn't find a match with other identical objects that are already on the list(I might be completely wrong).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class archive {
    
    private String indentifier;
    private String name;
    
    public archive(String indentifier,String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.indentifier = indentifier;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.indentifier + ": "+this.name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<archive> arhivs = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String indentifier, name;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Indentifier? (empty will stop)");
            indentifier = scan.nextLine();
            if(indentifier.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Name?(empty will stop)");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            if(name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            archive newAr = new archive(indentifier,name);
            
            if(arhivs.contains(newAr)) {
                System.out.println("Item is on the list");
            }else {
                arhivs.add(newAr);
            }
            
            
        }
        System.out.println("==Items==");
        for(archive arhivi:arhivs) {
            System.out.println(arhivi);
        }
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Class names in Java should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Well yes, if you construct a new `archive` it will be a unique object and not equal to anything in your ArrayList. You can instead loop through and compare the `indentifier` and/or `name` values to check for duplicates.

Comment: the contains method uses the equals() method to check if objects are equal. Since your `archive` class does not overwrite `equals`, this doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: So I have to make my own equals method and loop through each object?

Comment: @user16731988 not a loop, just override the `equals` method to compare whichever values you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Override `equals` (& `hashCode`)

You neglected to provide overrides of the inherited [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`Object#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods.

The default implementation of `equals` uses identity to compare, that is, "Do the two object references being compared share the same implicit memory address?".

Instead, you want to compare the *contents* of the two objects. So you need to write that content-comparison code in your own `equals` method. And whenever overriding `equals`, it is generally best to override `hashCode` using the same logic.

Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) will assist you in writing that code. For example, in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), see [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html) and [this discussion](http://#%20Override%20%60equals%60%20(and%20%60hashCode%60)%20%20You%20neglected%20to%20provide%20overrides%20of%20the%20inherited%20%5B%60Object#equals%60%5D%5B1%5D%20and%20%5B%60Object#hashCode%60%5D%5B2%5D%20methods.%20%20%20The%20default%20implementation%20of%20%60equals%60%20uses%20identity%20to%20compare,%20that%20is,%20%22Do%20the%20two%20object%20references%20being%20compared%20share%20the%20same%20implicit%20memory%20address?%22.%20%20%20Instead,%20you%20want%20to%20compare%20the%20*contents*%20of%20the%20two%20objects.%20So%20you%20need%20to%20write%20that%20content-comparison%20code%20in%20your%20own%20%60equals%60%20method.%20And%20whenever%20overriding%20%60equals%60,%20it%20is%20generally%20best%20to%20override%20%60hashCode%60%20using%20the%20same%20logic.%20%20%20Your%20%5BIDE%5D%5B3%5D%20will%20assist%20you%20in%20writing%20that%20code.%20For%20example,%20see%20%5Bthis%20documentation%5D(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html)%20for%20%5BIntelliJ%5D%5B5%5D.%20%20%20This%20issue%20has%20been%20covered%20many%20times%20on%20Stack%20Overflow.%20So%20%5Bsearch%20to%20learn%20more%5D%5B4%5D.%20%20%20##%20Records%20%20By%20the%20way,%20you%20can%20more%20briefly%20define%20your%20class%20as%20a%20%5Brecord%5D%5B6%5D.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20Archive%20(%20String%20identifier%20,%20String%20name%20)%20%7B%7D%20%20A%20record%20is%20appropriate%20when%20the%20main%20purpose%20of%20your%20class%20is%20to%20communicate%20data%20transparently%20and%20immutably.%20The%20compiler%20implicitly%20creates%20the%20constructor,%20getters,%20%60equals%60%20&%20%60hashCode%60,%20and%20%60toString%60%20methods.%20%20%20So%20using%20a%20record%20makes%20your%20problem%20moot.%20The%20%60equals%60%20&%20%60hashCode%60%20are%20done%20for%20you.%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()%20%20%20%5B3%5D:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment%20%20%20%5B4%5D:%20https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20override%20equals%20hashcode&t=osx&ia=web%20%20%20%5B5%5D:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA%20%20%20%5B6%5D:%20https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

This issue has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. So [search to learn more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20override%20equals%20hashcode&t=osx&ia=web).

### Records

By the way, you can more briefly define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Archive ( String identifier , String name ) {}
```

A record is appropriate when the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably.

The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString` methods.

So using a **record makes your problem moot**, assuming you want to compare each and every member field on the class. The `equals` & `hashCode` overrides are provided for you.